# AWK - comparing two files with a key and printing a summary(missing, same, different)

Tags: awk, compare

I have two files that look like this.  Both files are sorted on the 1st then 2nd field. (There can be multiple rows for an ID)

file a

```
3337312|6dc1d4397108002245c770fa66ee4d7767dcc23e|1
3337313|cb1c00eeccb25ea5a069da63a1b0c2565379ff9c|1
3337318|61a813730578c552b62de5618e1d66b1eb74b4f8|1
3337319|6af3b98f25a6a9b9d887486aefddfb53947bbf1c|1
3337320|1e3126f41f848509efad0b3415b003704377778c|1
```

file b

```
3337312|6dc1d4397108002245c770fa66ee4d7767dcc23e|1
3337315|780055f13efffcb4bee115c6cf546af85ac6c0a7|1
3337316|19535297b9913b6bca1796b68505498d5e81b5ed|1
3337318|61a813730578c552b62de5618e1d66b1eb74b4f8|1
3337319|6af3b98f25a6a9b9d887486aefddfb53947bbf1c|1
```

The first row is a key; 3 fields, pipe separated.  Files are roughly 1gb.
What I'd like to do is get back a result set that looks like:

```
3333 rows in File A
4444 rows in File B
1234 rows are identical 
2345 rows are different (aka the 2nd/3rd field are different but the key matches)
111  rows in File A not in File B
222  rows in File B not in File A
```

Here's SQL code that accomplishes it, and that's my fallback.

```
--CREATE TABLE aws_hash_compare (the_filename VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, switch_id BIGINT, hash_value CHAR(40),the_count TINYINT)

--CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ucidx__awshashcompare__the_filename__switch_id ON aws_hash_compare(the_filename, switch_id)

DECLARE @mSsql_filename sysname = 'FileA'
DECLARE @mYsql_filename sysname = 'FileB'


SELECT COUNT(*) AS MSSQL FROM aws_hash_compare 
WHERE the_filename = @mSsql_filename

SELECT COUNT(*) AS MYSQL FROM aws_hash_compare 
WHERE the_filename = @mYsql_filename 


SELECT COUNT(*) AS switch_id_match FROM aws_hash_compare mysql 
INNER JOIN aws_hash_compare mssql 
ON mysql.the_filename = @mYsql_filename 
AND mssql.the_filename = @mSsql_filename
AND mysql.switch_id = mssql.switch_id

SELECT COUNT(*) AS complete_match FROM aws_hash_compare mysql 
INNER JOIN aws_hash_compare mssql 
ON mysql.the_filename = @mYsql_filename 
AND mssql.the_filename = @mSsql_filename
AND mysql.switch_id = mssql.switch_id
AND mssql.hash_value = mysql.hash_value
AND mssql.the_count = mysql.the_count

SELECT COUNT(*) AS hash_differences FROM aws_hash_compare mysql 
INNER JOIN aws_hash_compare mssql 
ON mysql.the_filename = @mYsql_filename 
AND mssql.the_filename = @mSsql_filename
AND mysql.switch_id = mssql.switch_id
AND (mssql.hash_value <> mysql.hash_value OR mssql.the_count <> mysql.the_count)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS missing_from_MSSQL FROM aws_hash_compare mysql WHERE the_filename = @mYsql_filename 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM aws_hash_compare mssql WHERE the_filename = @mSsql_filename 
                AND mssql.switch_id = mysql.switch_id)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS missing_from_MYSQL FROM aws_hash_compare mssql WHERE the_filename = @mSsql_filename
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM aws_hash_compare mysql WHERE the_filename = @mYsql_filename
                AND mssql.switch_id = mysql.switch_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following awk could help you in same.

```
awk -F"|" '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]=$0;
  b[$1];
  next
}
FNR==1{
  file1_count=(NR-1) " rows in " ARGV[1]
}
($1 in b) && !($0 in a){
  first_field_matching++
}
($0 in a){
  common++;
  delete a[$0];
  next
}
{
  found_in_B_not_in_A++
}
END{
  found_in_A_not_in_B=length(a);
  print file1_count RS FNR " rows in " ARGV[2] RS common " rows are identical" \
RS first_field_matching " rows are different (aka the 2nd/3rd field are\
different but the key matches)" RS found_in_A_not_in_B " rows in File A\
not in File B" RS found_in_B_not_in_A " rows in File B not in File A"
}
' file_A file_B
```

Let's say following are File A and File B(I have done a minor change into your provided Input_files in order to verify one condition where $1 is same NOT others).

```
cat file_A
3337312|6dc1d4397108002245c770fa66ee4d7767dcc23e|1
3337313|cb1c00eeccb25ea5a069da63a1b0c2565379ff9c|1
3337318|61a813730578c552b62de5618e1d66b1eb74b4f8|1
3337319|786af3b98f25a6a9b9d887486aefddfb53947bbf1c|1
3337320|1e3126f41f848509efad0b3415b003704377778c|1

cat file_B
3337312|6dc1d4397108002245c770fa66ee4d7767dcc23e|1
3337315|780055f13efffcb4bee115c6cf546af85ac6c0a7|1
3337316|19535297b9913b6bca1796b68505498d5e81b5ed|1
3337318|61a813730578c552b62de5618e1d66b1eb74b4f8|1
3337319|6af3b98f25a6a9b9d887486aefddfb53947bbf1c|1
```

Now when we run above code then following will be the output on same.

```
5 rows in file_A
5 rows in file_B
2 rows are identical
1 rows are different (aka the 2nd/3rd field aredifferent but the key matches)
3 rows in File Anot in File B
3 rows in File B not in File A
```

Comment: @mbourgon, I'm curious about how long this will take with 1gb files, and how much memory is consumed. If you could, please let me know.

Comment: And a speed comparison vs sql

Comment: @mbourgon, your welcome. I am no expert in sql tried this in awk, will be good learning to know results. Keep learning and keep sharing cheers.

Comment: I think here the number of rows in A not B (and vice versa) should be 2: @mbourgon, consider key = 3337319: that counts as 1 "rows are different" AND a row in file A not in B AND a row in file B not in A -- if it's a "rows are different", should it be counted in "A not in B"?

Comment: @glennjackman, I made a small change in file_A to satisfy all conditions which I had mentioned in explanation sir.

Comment: I saw that, but should that row count for **both** "rows are different" **and** "not in file B"? I think only the OP can answer that q.

Comment: @glennjackman, apologies if I understand correctly here you mean to say count for "rows in File A not in File B" and "rows in File B not in File A" shouldn't be 3 because they have 1 common $1 line in them? Not sure if I get it correctly.

Comment: right. file A has 5 lines: 5 != 2 identical lines + 1 line with same key as file B + 3 lines not in file B.

Comment: @glennjackman I would say that 3337319 counts as a "rows are different" and should not be in "A not in B". The key exists in both, so it should be: 5 in a, 5 in B, 2 identical, 1 different, 2 in A not in B (313,320), and 2 in B not in A (315,316).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that uses `comm` to compare the files, then awk to generate the results. It might be slower but may use less memory. `comm` requires that its input files be sorted.

I'm assuming that a key appears exactly once per file.

```
comm filea fileb | awk -F'\t' '
    BEGIN { na = nb = identical = common = 0 }
    $1 {
        split($1, f, /[|]/)
        if (f[1] in b) {common++; delete b[f[1]]} else {a[f[1]]}
        na++
    }
    $2 {
        split($2, f, /[|]/)
        if (f[1] in a) {common++; delete a[f[1]]} else {b[f[1]]}
        nb++
    }
    $3 {
        identical++
        na++
        nb++
    }
    END {
        printf "%d rows in file A\n", na
        printf "%d rows in file B\n", nb
        printf "%d rows are identical\n", identical
        printf "%d rows are different but share a key\n", common
        printf "%d rows in file A only\n", length(a)
        printf "%d rows in file B only\n", length(b)
    }
'
```

Comment: Ran it on one of the tests and got the same results as SQL & the other awk script (Sweet!).  However, we may have multiple instances of the key in a file - that's why I include the count (3rd field), in case of multiple hashes for different rows with the same switch_id.  I'm currently waiting on someone to get the "full" files to compare.  Once I get those I'll share time and memory to run both versions. Thanks again!